# How do I know whether the compiler has ARC support enabled?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I need to write a lib in my iOS app.

The statement should be pre-process define as :

```
myObject ...

#if ARC
   // do nothing
#else
   [myObject release]
#endif
```

or run-time process as:

```
if (ARC) {
   // do nothing
} else {
   [myObject release];
}
```

How can I do?

Please help me! Thank you.

Comment: @Sulthan, there are reasonable use cases for the feature. Like making sure you library’s users don’t just grab your ARC-enabled sources and compile them without ARC support, leaking memory all over the place (happened to me a few days ago). That said, the sample code given in the question does look messy indeed.

Comment: @zoul You can never prepare for everything the user can do. In your case a simple assertion if ARC is on would be enough. Trying to have code compatible with both ARC and MRC must end in a very complicated code (or mess), with poor readibility. And code that is not readable is difficult to mantain.

Comment: Agreed, the assert is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `__has_feature`, like so:

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
// ARC is On
#else
// ARC is Off
#endif
```

If you want to also build with GCC (Apple's GCC does not support ARC), you may also need the following to determine the compiler:

```
#if defined(__clang)
// It's Clang
#else
// It's GCC
#endif
```

**Update**

Combined, they would take the general form:

```
 #if defined(__clang)     

 #if !defined(__has_feature)
 // idk when clang introduced this
 #error This version of clang does not support __has_feature
 #endif

 #define MON_IS_ARC_ENABLED_IN_THIS_TRANSLATION __has_feature(objc_arc)

 #else
 // for every compiler other than clang:

 #if defined(__has_feature)
 #error Another compiler supports __has_feature
 #endif

 #define MON_IS_ARC_ENABLED_IN_THIS_TRANSLATION 0

 #endif
```

Then just use `MON_IS_ARC_ENABLED_IN_THIS_TRANSLATION` in your sources or for further `#define`s.

If a compiler you use adds support, you would have to add a case for that (and compiler errors would likely catch the error in this case, since it would likely forbid use of ref count ops).

Note that this has extra checks to demonstrate how one can (and should) avoid defining reserved identifiers (based on a conversation in the comments). It's not exhaustive, but a demonstration. If you find yourself writing conditional `__has_feature` checks often, you may want to define a new macro for that to reduce and simplify definitions.

Comment: Don't check for compiler identity, check for compatibility. Use [#ifdef __has_feature](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#__has_feature_extension) as recommended by clang.

Comment: @Jesper I consider clang's recommendation a mistake. a) It can fail (rather easily). b) You should not declare that which is reserved for the compiler and/or implementation - specifically, from your link: `#define __has_feature(x) 0  // Compatibility with non-clang compilers.`

Comment: @Jesper the failure happens because other compilers (including GCC) just don't define or support `__has_feature`. It happens to work with GCC on Apple systems because CFBase.h defines it. If you don't include CoreFoundation directly (or indirectly), the results are wrong -- and Point B is still a severe problem. Here's one real world implementation which supports several compilers: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0_beta1/boost/type_traits/intrinsics.hpp

Comment: @Justin: Isn't checking if a compiler-specific reserved keyword is available and then selectively replacing it with a noop the only reasonable way of doing it? What if you check for GCC and they then provide __has_feature?

Comment: @Jesper we should not redefine what is reserved for the implementation. and no, it's not the only reasonable way to do it. personally, i'd just create a macro or `#define` here -- with compiler  defined checks. illustration in update (above), which also demonstrates detection of changes to definition of `__has_feature`. defining reserved identifiers is not required here, and should always be avoided.

Comment: @Justin: That's very pure but I'm not sure it's very useful. We'll have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it using macros:

```
#if !defined(__clang__) || __clang_major__ < 3
    #ifndef __bridge
        #define __bridge
    #endif

    #ifndef __bridge_retain
        #define __bridge_retain
    #endif

    #ifndef __bridge_retained
        #define __bridge_retained
    #endif

    #ifndef __autoreleasing
        #define __autoreleasing
    #endif

    #ifndef __strong
        #define __strong
    #endif

    #ifndef __unsafe_unretained
        #define __unsafe_unretained
    #endif

    #ifndef __weak
        #define __weak
    #endif
#endif

#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    #define SAFE_ARC_PROP_RETAIN strong
    #define SAFE_ARC_RETAIN(x) (x)
    #define SAFE_ARC_RELEASE(x)
    #define SAFE_ARC_AUTORELEASE(x) (x)
    #define SAFE_ARC_BLOCK_COPY(x) (x)
    #define SAFE_ARC_BLOCK_RELEASE(x)
    #define SAFE_ARC_SUPER_DEALLOC()
    #define SAFE_ARC_AUTORELEASE_POOL_START() @autoreleasepool {
    #define SAFE_ARC_AUTORELEASE_POOL_END() }
#else
    #define SAFE_ARC_PROP_RETAIN retain
    #define SAFE_ARC_RETAIN(x) ([(x) retain])
    #define SAFE_ARC_RELEASE(x) ([(x) release])
    #define SAFE_ARC_AUTORELEASE(x) ([(x) autorelease])
    #define SAFE_ARC_BLOCK_COPY(x) (Block_copy(x))
    #define SAFE_ARC_BLOCK_RELEASE(x) (Block_release(x))
    #define SAFE_ARC_SUPER_DEALLOC() ([super dealloc])
    #define SAFE_ARC_AUTORELEASE_POOL_START() NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    #define SAFE_ARC_AUTORELEASE_POOL_END() [pool release];
#endif
```

The above came from the site: http://raptureinvenice.com/arc-support-without-branches/; but I've pasted it to ensure it's not lost.

Answer (score 2):

You generally do not want to do things like this:

```
#if ARC
   // do nothing
#else
   [myObject release]
#endif
```

Because it’s a recipe for disaster, there are many subtle bugs lurking in such code. But if you do have a sane use case for that, you would perhaps be better off with a macro (I didn’t know `__has_feature`, thanks Justin!):

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    #define MY_RELEASE(x) while (0) {}
#else
    #define MY_RELEASE(x) [x release]
#endif
```

But I would be quite nervous to use even this, the pain potential is huge :)