# using a XMLRPC Library configured for ARC, getting an ARC error

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using the [XMLRPC library](https://github.com/eczarny/xmlrpc) that is set up to handle ARC and non-ARC projects. When i try to pass it a NSError object, i'm getting the error:

```
Implicit conversion of an Objective-C point to 'NSError *_autoreleasing *' is disallowed with ARC
```

and a warning:

```
Incompatible point types sending 'NSError *_strong' to parameter of type 'NSError *_autoreleasing *'
```

here is the method:

```
+ (XMLRPCResponse *)sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest: (XMLRPCRequest *)request error: (NSError **)error {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
    NSData *data = [[[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: [request request] returningResponse: &response error: error] retain] autorelease];
#else
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: [request request] returningResponse: &response error: error];
#endif

    if (response) {
        NSInteger statusCode = [response statusCode];

        if ((statusCode < 400) && data) {
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
            return [[[XMLRPCResponse alloc] initWithData: data] autorelease];
#else
            return [[XMLRPCResponse alloc] initWithData: data];
#endif
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Here is my attempt to call it:

```
NSError *myError;

XMLRPCResponse *serverResponse = [XMLRPCConnection sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest:request error:myError];
```

I guess i am unfamiliar with the

```
#if
```

syntax, but i'm guessing it acts just like a regular If statement?

I also have ARC enabled:

[image]

Should i just redo the XMLRPCResponse method to remove handling of non-ARC projects or is there a reason i'm getting the error/warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this answer here:

[How do I know whether the compiler has ARC support enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462372/how-do-i-know-whether-the-compiler-has-arc-support-enabled)

What compiler are you using? It might not support `__has_feature`

Regarding the error.. you should do something along the lines of:

```
NSError *error = nil;
XMLRPCResponse *serverResponse = [XMLRPCConnection sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest:request error:&error];
```

As the method takes a double pointer for the error argument.

Comment: Ok that shouldn't be the problem then. I've read your post more carefully and edited my answer.

Comment: yep, that's it; the method wanted a pointer to the error. Thanks!