# How do I prove ARC is working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a non-ARC project that I added a new file to and set an ARC compiler flag (-fobjc-arc) for.  When I make calls to [object release]; in the file, there are no compiler errors thrown.  I need to be sure that this file indeed has ARC enabled, how can I prove that?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462372/how-do-i-know-whether-the-compiler-has-arc-support-enabled

Comment: Nope. dealloc is still there to handle CF cleanup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no check for ARC at runtime. However, you can check it at compile time:

```
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    //Do the old stuff
#endif
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  I set the compiler flag on the wrong target BTW... that was the problem...

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you can call `-release`, ARC is off. Once turned on, the compiler will complain about any attempt at manual memory management, like calling `-retain`, `-release` or `[super dealloc]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    // ARC is On
    NSLog(@"ARC on");

#else
    // ARC is Off
    NSLog(@"ARC off");

#endif
```

Hope it helps you..