# How to write code using ARC feature of Objective C so that it can work on prior version of iOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c-runtime

As per my knowledge ARC is available from iOS SDK version 5.
So if you are writing an Objective C code using ARC syntax/features...how does one ensure that it works on the prior version of iOS ?

Comment: Are you asking how to write iOS 4 compatible code—in 2014?

Comment: If you are writing a new app now, you should only support iOS 7 and later.

Comment: You should not worry about ARC support.

Comment: These are valid points.  iOS4 has to be a fraction of a percent of the total iOS market at this point.  It doesn't even register [here](https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_frag).  A year ago it was [less than 4%](http://appleinsider.com/articles/13/12/05/apple-pegs-ios-7-distribution-at-74-ios-6-at-22).

Comment: You can write it without ARC, that's still absolutely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... `#ifdef`s, lots of `#ifdef`s.

For example, from [twitter-text-objc](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-objc/blob/master/lib/TwitterTextEntity.m):

```
...
#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)
    [entity autorelease];
#endif
    return entity;
}
```

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9462395/74815) you may find relevant.